# EPPlus выдает Error saving file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

Для работы с Excel использую библиотеку EPPlus.
Выгружаю данные с картинками (1635 шт). 
При сохранении выдает ошибку "Error saving file".
в InnerException лежит "Выдано исключение типа "System.OutOfMemoryException"".

Вот StackTrace

```
в System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
в System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
в System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
в OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zip.CountingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) в d:\EPPlus\Packaging\DotNetZip\Shared.cs:строка 813
в OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zlib.ZlibBaseStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) в d:\EPPlus\Packaging\DotNetZip\Zlib\ZlibBaseStream.cs:строка 160
в OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zlib.DeflateStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) в d:\EPPlus\Packaging\DotNetZip\Zlib\DeflateStream.cs:строка 617
в OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Crc.CrcCalculatorStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) в d:\EPPlus\Packaging\DotNetZip\CRC32.cs:строка 710
в OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zip.ZipOutputStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) в d:\EPPlus\Packaging\DotNetZip\ZipOutputStream.cs:строка 1290
в OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.ZipPackagePart.WriteZip(ZipOutputStream os) в d:\EPPlus\Packaging\ZipPackagePart.cs:строка 149
```

Каким образом можно решить проблему? объем ОЗУ 16гб
Размер одной картинки максимум 200 кб

Comment: Вы используете visual studio? Попробуйте выставить конечную платформу -> x64

Comment: Сколько памяти съедает ваше приложение? Вы измеряли это? Где оно столько съедает? Какое значение передается сюда `System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)`?

Comment: Судя по всему, пытается создаться excel файл размера больше например 2гб.

Comment: @yolosora, нет, x64 не подойдет, так как программа должна работать на windows x32

Comment: @Monk, такого не может быть, т.к. файл без картинок весит 500кб, а картинки в общей сложности не превышают и 150мб. Размер одной картинки в среднем 70кб. Есть картинки и по 200кб, но их мало

Comment: @tym32167, в диспетчере задач приложение в данном случае под отладчиков весит 404584кб

Comment: на строке `в OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.Ionic.Zip.CountingStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count) в d:\EPPlus\Packaging\DotNetZip\Shared.cs:строка 813` значения передаются 8096, 0, 8096. значение на момент вставки MemoryStream.Length = 161412349

Comment: Видимо, нужен воспроизводимый пример, без него можно только гадать

Comment: пример не получится предоставить, т.к. проблема именно при выгрузки с картинками. без картинок все в порядке. Причем, если выгружать с малым количеством картинок, то тоже, выгружается без проблем